# How do I make duplicates in a existing column unique?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, navicat

I am using MySQL 5.6 Server. I use Navicat to work in the DB.

I have searched and found a lot of possible solutions to my problem but none of them have worked for me.

I have a table with around 36000 rows. I have a column which allows duplicate entries but I would like to make the duplicates in the row unique. [Column with duplicates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqeFr.png)

I can find my duplicates using this query.
But there are too many to manually edit them all. [Search Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFSKi.png)

```sql
SELECT name, COUNT(ItemTemplate_ID) 
FROM itemtemplate
GROUP BY ItemTemplate_ID
HAVING ( COUNT(ItemTemplate_ID) > 1 )
```

What I am looking for is a way to do one of these things.

**Update the duplicates with new unique entries.**

**Add a text entry in another column for every duplicates. (I have a couple of empty columns I can use to add some text too.**

**Update the entire column with unique entries. (Doesn't matter what its called it just has to be unique.)**

Thanks in advance.

Edit - There already is a unique column called Id_nb.
The column I want to change entries in should not be unique.

Comment: Do you have a unique column in the table?

Comment: Yes i have a unique column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume that you do not have a unique column in the table.  If so, you can do this with variables:

```
set @rn := 0;
set @it := '';

update itemtemplate it
    set it.ItemTemplate_ID = (case when @it = it.ItemTemplate_ID
                                   then concat_ws('_', it.name, (@rn := @rn + 1))
                                   when @it := it.ItemTemplate_ID
                                   then if(@rn := 0, it.ItemTemplate_ID, it.ItemTemplate_ID)
                                   else if(@rn := 0, it.ItemTemplate_ID, it.ItemTemplate_ID)
                              end)
    order by it.ItemTemplate_ID;
```

This method does assume that there are not already columns with names like "ABC" and "ABC_1".

Comment: Im guessing this wont work when i have a unique column allready. My unique column is called Id_nb.

Comment: Well it kinda worked it seems. It went from 560+ duplicates to 27 duplicates.   I think i can manually fix the rest. Thanks for the help Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

**Update the duplicates with new unique entries.**

Let's assume that you have a unique column named id.

```
update itemtemplate set ItemTemplate_ID = (select md5(uuid())) where 
FIND_IN_SET(id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM itemtemplate GROUP BY ItemTemplate_ID HAVING ( COUNT(ItemTemplate_ID) > 1 ) ));
```

**Add a text entry in another column for every duplicates. (I have a couple of empty columns i can use to add some text too.**

```
update itemtemplate set ItemTemplate_ID = (select md5(uuid())), emptyColumn='text' where 
FIND_IN_SET(id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM itemtemplate GROUP BY ItemTemplate_ID HAVING ( COUNT(ItemTemplate_ID) > 1 ) ));
```

Sorry, I don't quite understand the third question.
By the way,if you have executed the first sql, the second sql will not work anymore.

Comment: The third one was to pretty much just clear all entrys in the column and start from scratch with unique entries. Like 1 2 3 4 etc. The answer i got from Gordon worked pretty well though. Gonna try these two also to see how it works.

Comment: Tried them both. Cant seem to get them working. Should probably have said im kinda new to this database stuff. Do i change the 2x id to my unique id column ?

Comment: First , yes you should change all the "id" to "Id_nb"

Comment: Second, if the ItemTemplate_ID  column is already unique, those two will not work anymore.

Comment: Im getting an error when trying the second query. [SQL] update itemtemplate set ItemTemplate_ID = (select md5(uuid())), PackageID='Duplicates' where 
FIND_IN_SET(Id_nb,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Id_nb) FROM itemtemplate GROUP BY ItemTemplate_ID HAVING ( COUNT(ItemTemplate_ID) > 1 ) ));
[Err] 1093 - You can't specify target table 'itemtemplate' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault, try this out "update itemtemplate set ItemTemplate_ID = (select md5(uuid())), PackageID='Duplicates' where FIND_IN_SET(Id_nb,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Id_nb) FROM (sellect * from itemtemplate ) temp GROUP BY ItemTemplate_ID HAVING ( COUNT(ItemTemplate_ID) > 1 ) ));"

Comment: And, the first one should be "update itemtemplate set ItemTemplate_ID = (select md5(uuid())) where 
FIND_IN_SET(id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM (select * from itemtemplate) temp GROUP BY ItemTemplate_ID HAVING ( COUNT(ItemTemplate_ID) > 1 ) ));"